# ruby-progressbar and stdout

Tags: ruby, progress-bar, stdout

Suppose I have a method which computes hard problems (maybe a depth-first search in a huge graph), we can call this method `dfs(graph)`.
This method also output to `stdout` each result reached, using `puts result`.

```ruby
def dfs(graph)
  while true
    # lots of computation

    result = something_reached
    puts result
  end
end
```

I want to display a progressbar in shell to show that computation is running, so I add an instance like this:

```ruby
pbar = ProgressBar.create(title: "Computing", starting_at: 1, total: nil)
```

and progressbar status must be updated (`pbar.increment`) as computation is running.

In a shell, I execute my program like this:

```bash
ruby dfs.rb > dfs_results.txt
```

**Issues**:

- With `pbar` is flushed to `stdout` so prograss-bar is redirected to `dfs_results.txt` and computation results are not store in this file.
  Without `pbar` result data is stored in file as is expected, but obviously without progress-bar.

  I know that results could be stored with `File.open` usage, but **it is desirable done with shell redirections**.

**Question**:

How should I be implemented to flush computation resulta to `dfs_results.txt` file and show a progress-bar to keep a executing progress for user?

Answer (score 1):

Just open a file to log into:

```
log = File.open('dfs_results.txt', 'w') 

# write into log file
log.write(result)
```

And your progressbar still writes to stdout. When you open a second screen you can follow the output with:

```
tails -f dfs_results.txt
```

**Update:** Or you can use stdout for the progressbar and stderr for the output of the script. Instead of `puts result` write:

```
$stderr.puts results
```

and start the script with:

```
ruby dfs.rb 2> dfs_results.txt
```

I still think the first version is better because results are not errors...

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion is a good alternative solution. I have specified a restriction. I hope that it could be done  with shell redirections, instead of open files from my program.